# Undefined Method - Calling a class in one file from another

Tags: ruby

I am trying to learn a little about GUI testing with Ruby & Cucumber, partially following a book called "Scripted GUI Testing with Ruby" by Ian Dees. I'm new to Ruby, and I'm facing what seems like a simple problem - undefined method. I have two classes, each in different modules. The first class will handle Win32API calls, the second represents the top level of the application (boot-up, close, find window etc). They will work a little like page objects, separating UI interaction logic from test logic. I'm getting an undefined method on the Windows API class, for user32:

```
#Win32API class

require 'Win32API'

class WindowsAPI

    def user32(name, param_types, return_value)
        Win32API.new 'user32', name, param_types, return_value
    end

    @find_window = user32 'FindWindow', ['P', 'P'], 'L'

end
```

The second:

```
#Application class

require_relative 'WindowsAPI'

class VideoLibrarian
    @main_win_title = "VidLibMainWin"
    attr_accessor :main_win_handle, :win_api

    def initialize
        @win_api = WindowsAPI.new
    end

    def Start()
        system 'start "" "C:/Users/VideoAnalyser.exe"'
        sleep 0.2 while (@main_win_handle = win_api.find_window.call nil, @main_win_title) <= 0
    end

end


vl = VideoLibrarian.new
vl.Start
```

The full stack trace/ error message is:

```
C:/Users/Ruby Scripts/vidlibtests/WindowsAPI.rb:11:in `<class:WindowsAPI>': undefined method `user32' for WindowsAPI:Class (NoMethodError)    
from C:/Users/Ruby Scripts/vidlibtests/WindowsAPI.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Users/Ruby Scripts/vidlibtests/VideoLibrarian.rb:3:in `require_relative'
from C:/Users/Ruby Scripts/vidlibtests/VideoLibrarian.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `user32` as an instance method while you clearly need it to be class method of `WindowsAPI` class:

```
def self.user32(name, param_types, return_value)
  Win32API.new 'user32', name, param_types, return_value
end
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to solve my immediate problem, but raises others. Guess I need to go away and read up on ruby scope. Thanks for your help!